# MinGW outputs a `*.0` file when I thought it would output a `*.dll` (Dynamic Link Library) & is only (roughly) half the size it should be

Tags: c, gcc, dll, tcl, mingw

I am trying to compile a TCL/TK package in MinGW on Windows 64-bit, which should (I think) output a Dynamic Link Library, but instead it outputs `*.0` file (which I have never heard of before), which is only (roughly) half the size it should be.
I am mostly new to MinGW and TCL/TK/C compiling so have no idea if this is normal or not.

What's more I don't know what TYPE of `*.0` file it is, according to https://fileinfo.com/extension/0 their are 5 types, but it will most likely be one of the first 2.

Git Bash output:

```
gcc -static-libgcc -pipe -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Tkhtml\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"tkhtml\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"3.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Tkhtml\ 3.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY
_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -DNO_SYS_WAIT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 -DUSE_THREAD_ALLOC=1 -D_REENTRANT=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DTCL_WIDE_INT_TYPE=long\ long -DHAVE_LSEEK64=1 -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TK_STUBS=
1   -I"C:/MinGW/include" -I"C:/MinGW/include"     -O2 -Wall -Wno-implicit-int  -c -I. -I../src `echo ../src/htmltext.c` -o htmltext.o
gcc -static-libgcc -pipe -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Tkhtml\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"tkhtml\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"3.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Tkhtml\ 3.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY
_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -DNO_SYS_WAIT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 -DUSE_THREAD_ALLOC=1 -D_REENTRANT=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DTCL_WIDE_INT_TYPE=long\ long -DHAVE_LSEEK64=1 -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TK_STUBS=
1   -I"C:/MinGW/include" -I"C:/MinGW/include"     -O2 -Wall -Wno-implicit-int  -c -I. -I../src `echo ../src/htmlutil.c` -o htmlutil.o
gcc -static-libgcc -pipe -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Tkhtml\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"tkhtml\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"3.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Tkhtml\ 3.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY
_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -DNO_SYS_WAIT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 -DUSE_THREAD_ALLOC=1 -D_REENTRANT=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DTCL_WIDE_INT_TYPE=long\ long -DHAVE_LSEEK64=1 -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TK_STUBS=
1   -I"C:/MinGW/include" -I"C:/MinGW/include"     -O2 -Wall -Wno-implicit-int  -c -I. -I../src `echo ../src/cssprop.c` -o cssprop.o
rm -f libTkhtml3.0
gcc -static-libgcc -pipe -shared -o libTkhtml3.0 css.o cssdynamic.o cssparser.o csssearch.o htmldraw.o htmlfloat.o htmlhash.o htmlimage.o htmlinline.o htmllayout.o htmlparse.o htmlprop.o htmlstyle.o htmltagdb.o htmltable.o htmltcl.o htmltree.o swproc.o restrack.o htmldec
ode.o htmltext.o htmlutil.o cssprop.o -L/mingw64/lib -ltclstub86 -L/mingw64/lib -ltkstub86
: libTkhtml3.0
echo 'package ifneeded Tkhtml 3.0 [list load [file join $dir libTkhtml3.0]]' > pkgIndex.tcl
echo 'package ifneeded hv3 0.1 [list source [file join $dir hv3-0.1.tm]]' >> pkgIndex.tcl
```

Comment: You have `-o libTkhtml3.0` in the last `gcc` command. That's not a `.0` file, it's a file ending in the version `3.0`.